# How to see Eclipse's project variables and their values?

Tags: eclipse, ide, environment-variables

I was working on an imported project with maven dependencies for jar packaging but a lot of variables I used were non-existent, such as ${container_loc} and so on, and I think I even had whitespace errors (not sure why I don't have them now).

Tried to print the variables but I am not sure printing them one by one is possible or feasible.

Edit: Thanks @howlger ${workspace_loc:\MyProject...} works.

Comment: Eclipse also seems to forget ${project_loc} in (Run as External Configuration). I am pretty sure that's a bug.

Comment: `${container_loc}` and `${project_loc}` require that a resource in your workspace is currently selected. If you want a specific resource use `${project_loc:<resource path>}` instead. See https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm

Comment: Thanks, that works. The way eclipse works is so weird and I am not sure what I encountered is a bug or intended even. I don't think running cmd with something selected from eclipse itself via. mouse is a good idea personally. It is at best counterintuitive imo.

Comment: I can't see anything weird here. It works as expected and as documented. The ability to use the selection as input for a command line tool is powerful and used by many. Remember, the _i_ in IDE stands for _integrated_. Please also note, in Eclipse variables are not only used in _External Tool_ configurations.

Comment: But the documentation felt pretty bad to me about that. Forgetting the selection by Eclipse after terminating doesn't make common sense either.

Comment: Then report a bug (with a patch) how to improve it.

Comment: Did it as I wrote, yes.